# Adding new key value to dictionary in a for loop

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I have a hugging face dataset in format

```
 test = [{'doc':document1, 'id':id1},{'doc':document2, 'id':id2}.......]
```

I'm trying to generate summaries for the dataset and append them to the doc.
The code below takes one dict from test and computes lex rank summary. This is stored in summary variable as a list (each list item is a summary). I want each summary to be appended to a new key called summary for each dict in dataset.

```
for i in test:
   segments = get_segmented_text(i['doc'])
   expected_length = round(len(segments) / median_compression_ratio)
   most_central_indices = compute_lexrank_sentences(model, segments, device, expected_length)
   summary = [segments[idx] for idx in sorted(most_central_indices)]
   i['summary'] = '\n'.join(summary)
```

This code supposed to add another key value with summaries but it doesn't add anything neither gives any error.

Here is expected output:

```
test = [{'doc':document1, 'id':id1, 'summary': summary1},{'doc':document2, 'id':id2, 'summary':summary2}.......]
```

Thanks in advance

**Edit:** I approached this problem by converting the huggingface dataset to dataframe and slight changes in code (code below). It works fine this way. But still I would like to know how to do this on huggingface dataset.

```
  for i, row in df.iterrows():
    segments = get_segmented_text(row['doc'])
    expected_length = round(len(segments) / median_compression_ratio)
    most_central_indices = compute_lexrank_sentences(model, segments, device, expected_length)

    summary = [segments[idx] for idx in sorted(most_central_indices)]
    df.at[i, 'summary'] = '\n'.join(bert_summary)
```

Comment: i cant see what goes wrong with only the codesnippet from above. print(summary) before you try to put it into test[i]

Comment: print(summary) outputs each summary in a list, ex: ['summary1'], ['summary2']

Answer (score 0):

Two things I'd like to ask here:

1. For each key-value pair, do you want your `summary` to be a list or a single value?
2. Output of your code before and after the loop.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question and should really be a comment.

Comment: I do not have enough reputation count :/

Comment: @ShashankTiwari For each dict, I need a key:summary and value:'generated summary'. 

Before loop the dataset looks like : test = [{'doc':document1, 'id':id1},{'doc':document2, 'id':id2}.......]

After loop it should look like: test = [{'doc':document1, 'id':id1, 'summary': summary1},{'doc':document2, 'id':id2, 'summary':summary2}.......]

Comment: The problem with your prior code is that the `summary` variable is a list, and you are trying to put it as a value (which is possible BTW). Since you're generating the whole list in a single go (inside the loop), I'm sure that the same `summary` variable is getting created/updated repeatedly. The best way to handle this would be to get a specific value for the `summary` key of all the dictionaries inside the list.